# Laravel File Uploading

Tags: laravel

I have tried the code below for uploading file to laravel but it always go to false (which is noimage.jpg). Links and everything are already linked up through artisan but the image doesnt seem to reach the storage folder. Below are my codes for file handling.

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[
            'title' => 'required',
            'body'=>'required', 
            'cover_image' => 'image|nullable|max:1999'

            ]);

            //Handle File pUpload
            if($request->hasFile('cover_image'))
            {
                //Get Filename with the Extension
                $filenameWithExt = $request->file('cover_image')->getClientOriginalName();
                //Get Just File Name
                $fileName = pathinfo($filenameWithExt,PATHINFO_FILENAME);
                //Get Just Extension
                $extension = $request->file('cover_image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
                //Filename to Store
                $fileNameToStore = $fileName.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;

                //upload of Image
                $path = $request->file('cover_image')->storeAs('public/cover_image',$fileNameToStore);
            } else {
                $fileNameToStore = 'noimage.jpg';
            }

            //Create Post
            $post = new Post;
            $post->title = $request->input('title');
            $post->body = $request->input('body');
            $post->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
            $post->cover_image = $fileNameToStore;
            $post->save();

            return redirect('/posts')->with('success','Post Created');
    }
```

on the Other hand,below is the code for the "Create Post".

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

<h1>Create Post</h1>

{!! Form::open(['action' => 'PostsController@store', 'POST','enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']) !!}
   <div class="form-group">
       {{Form::label('title','Title')}}
       {{Form::text('title', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placegholder' => 'Title'])}}
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">

    {{Form::label('body','Body')}}
    {{Form::textarea('body', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placegholder' => 'body'])}}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    {{Form::file('cover-image')}}   
</div>

{{Form::submit('Submit', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary'])}}
{!! Form::close() !!}
@endsection
```

but the result in the database is this.

[image]

Does anyone have any idea where I went wrong? Thank you so much.

Comment: Hey this is very old . Why dont you try with laravel storage which u can upload files just with a single code line rather than this bunch of code.

Comment: `$request->file('avatar')->store('avatars');` Just this code only

Comment: try this . ` $path = $request->file('cover_image')->move('cover_image',$fileNameToStore);`

Answer (score 0):

I can share you my library on uploading files

```
$file = $request->file('YOUR_FILE');

$ext = $file->getClientOriginalExtension()?: "txt";
$mime_type = $file->getMimeType()?:"plain/text";

$path_directory = "new_folder";

if (!File::exists(public_path($path_directory))){
    File::makeDirectory(public_path($path_directory), $mode = 0755, true, true);
}

$filename = Helper::create_filename($ext); //create_filename - Str:::random(6) or anything you want
$new_image_filename = $filename;
$file->move($path_directory, $filename);
```

Comment: actually this is only a small part on my File/ImageUploader  library that can handle 3rd party external storage like s3 / azure storage or other file servers